# Unable to save the content of the files into hash map properly

Tags: java, android, hash

Iam trying to insert the contents that is present in a file into a Hashmap.I figured out a way to do that.However,I am not getting the output i desired.Below mentioned is the code that does try to load file contents into a hashmap.

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{

    try {

        StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer(1000);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xxxxxxx"));
        char[] buf = new char[1024];

        int numRead=0;
        while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1){
            String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
            fileData.append(readData);
            buf = new char[1024];
        }

        reader.close();
        Map map = new HashMap();
         System.out.println(fileData.toString());->(1)

        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new  
         StringTokenizer(fileData.toString());
        while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            map.put(stringTokenizer.nextToken().toString(),stringTokenizer.nextToken().toString());
        }

        Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
            System.out.println("key"+m.getKey());->(2)
            System.out.println("value"+m.getValue());->(3)

        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

When i print from equation  1 mentioned in the code.I am getting the desired output(i.e Path as key and hash as value):

```
C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\input_3\com.AmazingBullshit.Holy_1.03.apk
66ec456315a7e6c9338b0387171ca89e
C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\input_3\com.amazon.venezia_release   
13.0003.844.1C_6430003104.apk
266796d1b8e2e016753ee3bf1b50e591 
C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\input_3\com.android.browser_4.4.2- 
eng.build.20150616.1901504.apk
4aa2091b0e21fc655e19d07e2ae20982
C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\input_3\com.android.calculator2_4.4.2- 
eng.build.20150616.1901504.apk
85313ccbd39a43952906b70b941d321b
C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\input_3\com.android.calendar_4.4.2- 
eng.build.20150616.1901504.apk
3c85cb87f2e134a4157e5f3747e4df1b
C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\input_3\com.android.camera2_2.0.002   
(eng.build.ef73894.060315_142358-70)4.apk
482205cda6991f89fb35311dea668013
```

However,when i kept it in the hash map and trying to print it (using eq(2) and eq(3)),I am getting a different output.

```
  key:
  dd383abe48e591f40504cbb4dff80958
  value:
   C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\input_3\com.android.quicksearchbox_4.4.2- 
   eng.build.20150616.1901504.apk
 key:
 482205cda6991f89fb35311dea668013
 value:
 C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\input_3\com.android.contacts_4.4.2-  
 eng.build.20150616.1901504.apk
 key:
 C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\input_3\com.AmazingHolyBull_1.03.apk
 value:
 66ec456315a7e6c9338b0387171ca89e
```

If you can observe the output has changed.Especially in the last two lines of the above output where the "key entry is the path" and "value entry is the hash ". I am unable to figure out an exact reason why the hashmap is giving a weird output.I am expecting an output that looks something like:

Key:   path of the .apk file
value: hash of the .apk file.
Similar to the first output.

Below attached is the way it is in the input file.

```
 C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\baal\apuslauncher-1.apk
 af05322cf2c682e8c04a0fb9441867f1
 C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\baal\apuslauncher-2.apk 
 af05322cf2c682e8c04a0fb9441867f1 
 C:\Users\rishii\Desktop\baal\apuslauncher.apk
af05322cf2c682e8c04a0fb9441867f1
```

Any Suggestions would be highly helpful!

Comment: Try to print output of each call to `stringTokenizer.nextToken().toString()`

Comment: It looks like every value is on a separate line. Is that true? If so, don't read entire file into memory, and don't use a `StringTokenizer`. Just use the [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method. --- Also, don't use `StringBuffer`, use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead. Javadoc of [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) says so.

Comment: @Andreas I want to save them into a hashmap

Comment: @mohanbabu That comment has nothing to do with what I said, so let me ask again: Are each value (path or hash) on separate lines, i.e. path in line 1, hash in line 2, path in line 3, hash in line 4, and so on?

Comment: @Andreas Yeah!But i assume you cannot do file operations using BufferedReader.inLine() in android

Comment: Why are you assuming that?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, just use the `BufferedReader.readLine()` method:

```
// Load file into map
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xxxxxxx"))) {
    String path, hash;
    while ((path = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if ((hash = reader.readLine()) == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Found path without hash");
        map.put(path, hash);
    }
}

// Print map
for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("path: " + entry.getKey());
    System.out.println("hash: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Android has got it's own way of file reading.If you have to read a file  in android studio it is  "InputStream XmlFileInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file_input_val);". The idea here is You have to save your file in the raw folder in your android studio.In this example,The name of my file is "file_input_val".I tried it the way told by you only to end up in vain 
.

Comment: I just went by your own code of using a `FileReader`. If you have to use `openRawResource` to get an `InputStream`, try using `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file_input_val)))`.